# read the output of a process while the process is running

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I need to start a process and read the output of that process while the process is running. I want to be able to print the output (optional) and to return the output when the process has finished. Here is what I have so far (merged from other answers in stackoverflow):

```
def call(command, print_output):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    out = ""

    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline().rstrip().decode("utf-8")
        if line == '':
            break

        if print_output:
            print(line)

        out += line + "\n"

    process.wait()

    return process.returncode, out
```

This code works great in windows (tested with windows 7, python 3.3) but fails in linux (Ubuntu 12.04, python 3.2). In linux, the script hangs at the line

```
line = process.stdout.readline().rstrip().decode("utf-8")
```

when the process has finished.

What's wrong with the code? I've tried to check whether the process has been finished with process.poll() as well, but that returns always None under Linux.

Comment: Works fine on my Linux, with 3.2, and not closing a closed fd seems to be an incredibly unlikely bug. What do you see when you `strace` the Python program? Also, can you include the value of `command` you're using?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The problem is really the command, it is an "svn export ..." and the svn process expects a user input the first time (login, passwort). Sorry for that...

Answer (score 0):

The docs say

```
Warning Use communicate() rather than 
.stdin.write, .stdout.read or .stderr.read to
avoid deadlocks due to any of the other OS pipe buffers filling 
up and blocking the child process.
```

I know I had issues before on Windows.

I presume the command is running in unbuffered mode somehow.

The docs have recipes for using subprocess your sounds like [shell-backquote](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-bin-sh-shell-backquote) yet your use of `subprocess` is different.