# Get output of os.system while the command is running

Tags: python, subprocess, python-os

I am making a program which is an interface for a command-line application. When running the command-line app directly through CMD it opens a new window and shows the percentage complete. I want to get this percentage from the running application and get it into Python and then the interface. It doesn't need to use os.system(), as long as it can start the application (with parameters) then it doesn't matter how it does it.

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18739239/python-how-to-get-stdout-after-running-os-system) however, it only gets the output once the whole process has finished running. I've also looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802224/read-the-output-of-a-process-while-the-process-is-running) however this doesn't provide a solution and is very old.
So is it possible to capture the output while it is still running at regular intervals?

Comment: You certainly cannot do that with `os.system()` - it doesn't return until the command finishes.  `subprocess.Popen()` is what you want - you can read from the returned object's `stdout` attribute to get real-time output.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.